# Do ASCII Point Clouds need R G B data?

Tags: point-clouds, lidar

I am trying to open NASA's Clementine LIDAR data of the Lunar surface (**Link:** https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/clementine/lidar.html). The data is saved as a `*.tab` file which is really an `ASCII` file. When I look for the data I need (x,y,z,r,g,b) I can only find data points `x,y,z` but not `r,g,b`.

**Main Question** If my goal is to open this file in `CloudCompare` and develop a mesh/dem file from this, do I need `r,g,b` data?

**Side Questions** If so, how do you recommend I get it from data that is from the 90s? Or atleast, how would I go about opening this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no need to have **R,G,B** in CloudCompare, but you definitely will have to prepare the data in the format that is readable by CloudCompare. That shouldn't be a problem using simple Python scripts. If you further help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the **RGB** data to open it on CloudCompare, just the point coordinates. There is no way of retrieving the radiometric information of this point cloud unless you have some imagery of the same epoch. Then you could associate the RGB to the point cloud by using [collinearity equations](https://doi.org/10.3390/s18061770), for instance.